# How to preserve line breaks?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

On jsp page I get content by ajax and put the result into html

```
$('#somediv').html(html);
```

From server side I send content:
`there is some text,<br/>and from here it starts from the next line`

How to preserve line breaks in page? Now they display just like text.

Comment: That is highly unlikely. If you get `<br/>` in the result they render. If you SEE the `<br/>` in the text, you need to unescape the data

Comment: @mplungjan not sure how ca I make that unescaping?

Comment: Try `$('#somediv').html('test<br>test')` in your web browsers console. Does it work as intended?

Comment: @CodyG. it works as expected adn what does it mean?

Comment: Okay, so now that you've verified that, verify that the (data) object from your AJAX is coming in properly. Are there extraneous characters that are included ? Or are the </br> tags just completely stripped?

Comment: @CodyG. finally I did it - there were that `html data` was not exactly a `data` but that was a jsp page returned from controller so using escapeXML='false' in jsp solves the issue but any way thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.parseHTML()

```
var htmlParsed=jQuery.parseHTML(html);
$('#somediv').html(htmlParsed);
```

Comment: I also checked in console $('#somediv').html(jQuery.parseHTML("there is some text,<br/>and from here it starts from the next line"));
This working fine

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call you can specify that you're expecting HTML.
For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your-url.html",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#somediv').html(data);
    }
});
```

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info

Comment: How should we know what you did. You did not post the ajax call